# How to edit permission of a folder with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a shared Google Drive. I am making edits to the drive as the owner of the drive.

Is there a way in Apps Script to edit the permission of a folder by the folder's id and the email address of the [user group](https://support.google.com/a/topic/25838?hl=en&ref_topic=9197&sjid=1015758226062715407-NC) I have to set permission for?

I came across [this article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission?hl=en) in Apps Script documentation but the `.setSharing()` method appears to only apply to ANYONE, DOMAIN etc but not to a custom user group via its email.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
const folderId = "###"; // Please set your folder ID.
const groupEmail = "###"; // Please set your group email address.

Drive.Permissions.insert({ role: "writer", type: "group", value: groupEmail }, folderId, { supportsAllDrives: true });
```

- When this script is run, when you have permission for the folder, the folder is shared with the group.
- Please modify `role: "writer"` to your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [Method: permissions.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/permissions/insert)